# Ubuntu Studio - Suddenly issue where some applicatons need sudo to run

Tags: sound, sudo, ubuntu-studio, jack, pipewire

I'm on Ubuntu Studio 22.04 LTS and suddenly I can't run Audacity, Qjackctl, Carla or plugdata without sudo on the terminal. If I launch them  from icon or from terminal with no sudo,they only appear in system monitor but not on the screen, simply they don't open at all. I'm not sure when it happened (maybe trying to set pipewire as default audio output which I reverted to keep sticking with pulseaudio and jack which it doesn't work now) or (maybe installing yabridge).
However, some others applications like pure data, Ardour and others work perfectly which is weird.
Please anyone can help me or have experienced a similar issue? Thanks in advance.